# How to determine that security descriptor changed without opening handle?

Tags: c++, windows, security, backup, ntfs

Imagine you have a large file share and you want to backup it when it's changed.
Changing a folder or a file security descriptor is also a change, but how can you determine one without opening a handle for every item on a share?

I thought that modifying the security descriptor (adding new user to access list, for ex) changes [ftLastWriteTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa365739(v=vs.85).aspx) attribute, but it doesn't.

The question is: is it possible to track a security info modification without reopening all files and retrieving security descriptor data?

Comment: you can call `ReadDirectoryChangesW` on (share and any) folder with *dwNotifyFilter* which include `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY`. as result you got `FILE_ACTION_MODIFIED` action with relative (folder) file name.

Comment: as I understand it will track changes only while the app is running, and it's not the case: the app is scheduled to run from time to time.

Comment: in this case you need `FSCTL_READ_USN_JOURNAL` with `USN_REASON_SECURITY_CHANGE` in `ReasonMask` (how minimum)

Comment: but this is worked only for local volumes

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. Looks like journal is what I need.

Comment: Meta-data changes to a file's attributes and security descriptor update its `ChangeTime`, if that field is supported (it's always 0 for FAT). Starting with Vista, you can call [`GetFileInformationByHandleEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364953) on a handle for the directory to query its [`FileIdBothDirectoryInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364226) entries.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But you have to open a file or directory handle to acquire that info. I think, I will make some experiments with GetFileInformationByHandleEx also. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can open a directory handle with `CreateFile` if you specify `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS`. As to the file listing, allocate a large buffer (e.g. 4 KB) and use two while loops. The outer loop calls `GetFileInformationByHandleEx` to read into the buffer. The inner loop processes the entries, advancing each iteration by `NextEntryOffset` until it's 0.

Comment: I forgot to mention that `GetFileInformationByHandleEx` will fail with `ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES` at the end of successfully reading the directory. Any other error code is really a failure.